# LXC container from Docker archive

Tags: docker, lxc

[This](https://asciinema.org/a/165784) resource gives a way to create an LXC container using `lxc-create` out of a standard Docker image `alpine`:

```
sudo lxc-create c2 -t oci -- --url docker://alpine
```

However, I would like to do this initially:

```
 docker save alpine > alpine.tar
```

After that, I would like to run the conversion on the `alpine.tar`, without preliminarily unpacking it. Is it possible, and if so, what is the exact format for the archive? I tried with e.g. `sudo lxc-create c3 -t oci -- --url docker://archive:alpine.tar`,
it give the error

```
FATA[0001] Error initializing source docker://archive:alpine.tar: Error reading manifest alpine.tar in docker.io/library/archive: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required 
lxc-create: c3: lxccontainer.c: create_run_template: 1621 Failed to create container from template
lxc-create: c3: tools/lxc_create.c: main: 319 Failed to create container c3
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow same steps as given in this link https://asciinema.org/a/165784

In below command why did you give c3 instead of c2 ?

*sudo lxc-create c3 -t oci -- --url docker://archive:alpine.tar*